# How to implement tour/activity availability management backend easiest way

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I am implementing some travel product booking project with codeigniter framework & mysql database.

The problem is there are different availability to those products and i want to save & fetch availability of product easily

When user searches by date i need to fetch available tours & activities on that date

Ex:

**Experiences**

Themeparks - It available everyday with opening & closing timing. User has to select date only to book it (for some parks one of the weekday will be holiday)

Cooking Classes - these will have slots, user has to book particular date & time slot on that day to book it

**Tours**

Group Tours - Provider will give fixed dates, user has to select from those dates to book it

Individual Tours - User can select any date to book it

I had to work on two individual scheduling solutions for experiences & tours. Please help me to do it

Comment: Help you do it? This reads more like a spec asking for us to do it. Try it yourself, if you have _specific_ programming issues, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use RRule to create scheduling like that

https://medium.com/@ScullWM/design-and-manage-recurring-events-fb43676e711a